# I hard regex to optional space character when I need get rid space character in output/replace

Tags: regex, regex-group

I tried many changes times but not work, 99% success match.

I want optional space properly. and replace group 1,2,3,4,5 without being space like `(.sys)` but not space `(.sys )`

regex search:

```
(?<size>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})+|[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+))[\t\x20]*(?<size_type>(?i)gb|mb|m|g)[\t\x20]*(?<file>.+(?=\.)|.+)(?<type>(?:\..*)?)\s*\|\s*(?<path>(?i:C|D):.*\\)
```

regex replace:

```
(\1)(\2)(\3)(\4)(\5)
```

Text:

```
3.9 GB pagefile.sys | C:\
3.9 GB pagefile.sys |C:\
3.9 GB pagefile.sys| C:\
3.9 GB pagefile.sys|C:\

3.9 GB pagefile.sys | C:\
3.9 GBpagefile.sys | C:\
3.9GB pagefile.sys | C:\
3.9GBpagefile.sys | C:\
```

expected behavior I want:

```
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)

(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
```

actual behavior:

```
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys )(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys )(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys)(C:\)

(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys )(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys )(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys )(C:\)
(3.9)(GB)(pagefile)(.sys )(C:\)
```

See regex101.com [here link](https://regex101.com/r/lZRNiX/1)

anyone help?

Comment: The `.*` matches too much. You could use for example `\S*` see https://regex101.com/r/GKtCTU/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: You could write this as an answer.

Comment: Why are you using named capture group in regex and positional groups in replacement? And what language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Toto I see some more possibilities to refactor the pattern :-) but you can post an answer if you want.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Sure, it really could be optimized. I let you do.

Comment: @Toto named capture group as comment because I read it. if I'm confuse when number group. ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see an extra space in the replacement is because the `.*` in in matching the type `(?<type>(?:\..*)?)` can also match a space.

You could restrict it using `\S*` matching optional non whitespace chars if there has to be at least a single dot.

The alternation for the size_type can also be written using character classes `(?<size_type>(?i)[gm]b|[mg])` and the same for the path `(?<path>(?i:[CD]):.*\\)`

The whole pattern could look like:

```
(?<size>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})+|[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+))[\t\x20]*(?<size_type>(?i)[gm]b|[mg])[\t\x20]*(?<file>.+(?=\.)|.+)(?<type>(?:\.\S*)?)\s*\|\s*(?<path>(?i:[CD]):.*\\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ob2SQm/1)

If there is always a pipe char and a single char C or D followed by `:\` another option could be:

```
(?<size>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})+|[0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+))[\t\x20]*(?<size_type>(?i)gb|mb|m|g)[\t\x20]*(?<file>[^\s|]+)(?<type>\.[^|\s]+)[\t\x20]*\|[\t\x20]*(?<path>(?i:[CD]):\\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEgMXD/1)